# Gmaps is not defined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-5, gmaps4rails

I´m developing an website in ROR

I am using gem 'gmaps4rails'.

In localhost the map is showed, but when i put on a production server (DigitalOcean) gives me this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Gmaps is not defined`

i have this script in my index.html.erb:

```
<div id="map_show" ></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">  
      handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map_show'}}, function(){
 markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);

  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
        </script>
```

My application.js is this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
//= require highcharts
//= require chartkick 
//= require_tree .
```

Anyone know how can i resolve my problem?

**EDIT 1**

Application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ThomarWeb - Site espectacular de Turismo</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "gmaps4rails" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "gmaps4rails" %>
    <!--<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA4BHW3txEdqfxzdTlPwaHsYRSZbfeIcd8&callback=initMap"
          async defer></script>-->

<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA4BHW3txEdqfxzdTlPwaHsYRSZbfeIcd8"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/mahnunchik/markerclustererplus/master/dist/markerclusterer.min.js"></script>
<script src='//cdn.rawgit.com/printercu/google-maps-utility-library-v3-read-only/master/infobox/src/infobox_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script> <!-- only if you need custom infoboxes -->

  </head>

  <body>

    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
            <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-info") %>
        <% end %>

        <%= yield %>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

I was following this tutorial: https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/16.04#nginx-passenger

***SOLVED!***

I solve my problem.
The problem is the javascripts files in the server.

I need to use CDN:

```
<script src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gmaps4rails/2.1.2/gmaps4rails.js'> </script>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js'> </script>
```

Comment: after running bundle, to install gmaps gem, have you reboot the server (rails server)?

Comment: yes, i do `passenger stop` and then `passenger start`

Comment: http://www.thomar.me:3000    this is the website. To view the error click in the monumentos in the navbar

Comment: have you run RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile since you changed the js file

Comment: Yes, i execute `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` and nothing happens

Comment: Still giving the error : `Uncaught ReferenceError: Gmaps is not defined`

Comment: Try to wrap your code in script type="text/javascript" $( document ).ready(function() {
    handler = Gmaps.build('Google'); ...
});

Comment: Can you paste application.html.erb or application.html.haml file here

Comment: I added the `application.html.erb` in tue question. I wrap the code but still have the error

Comment: Anyone have any solution?