# Rails 6 and Google Maps for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm using Rails 6.0.0.rc1 and hoping to implement the [Google-Maps-for-Rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails) gem. I installed underscore via [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/underscore) and added the required google scripts with my API in my  tag.

I download the `gmaps_google.js` and added it to my vendor/js folder as Rails 6 has no asset pipeline, instead uses webpacker. This is where I think to issue is as I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Gmaps
```

I updated my `webpacker.yml` file to look for the vendor/js folder and when checking the DOM it seems to be present.

**webpacker.yml**

```
# Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
resolved_paths: ['vendor/js']
```

In my `javascript/packs/application.js` I included a `require("gmaps_google")` line. Note, I had the same issue with Highcharts, but was able to load the script successfully but adding `window.Highcharts = Highcharts;` but I'm not sure if I can do the same with a require option?

**javascript/packs/application.js**

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require('jquery')
require("trix")
require("@rails/actiontext")

window.Highcharts = Highcharts;
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import addMore from "highcharts/highcharts-more";
import 'bootstrap'
import 'underscore'

require("gmaps_google")
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "app_name",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0-alpha",
    "@rails/actiontext": "^6.0.0-rc1",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0-alpha",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0-alpha",
    "@rails/webpacker": "^4.0.7",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "highcharts": "^7.1.2",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "trix": "^1.0.0",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.1"
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44704324/gmaps-is-not-defined

Comment: @DeepakMahakale link proved to be very helpful. I needed to add use the CDN links.

Comment: @DollarChills how / where did you add in the CDN links?  Did you have to rename `require("gmaps_google") to something else?

Comment: Add the CDN links in the head tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because of there aren't `export` statements in `gmaps_google.js`, you should convert anonymous functions to named function before that.

As an example:

```
// foo.js
// function need to be converted
(function() {
  // function body
}).call(this);
```

convert anonymous function to named function

```
// foo.js
function foo() {
  // function body
};

export { foo as Foo };
```

invoke `import` statement in another file.

```
// bar.js
import Foo from 'foo';

Foo();
```