# Gmaps with Rails 6/Webpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to get my Google Maps setup that previously worked with earlier versions of Rails to display using Rails 6. Obviously Rails 6 is now using webpack to handle javascript assets and I can't get my app to recognie the Gmaps function used to render the map.

Some of the basics:

Gemfile

```rb
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem 'underscore-rails'
# maybe don't need ^ this underscore gem anymore
```

I installed underscore with `yarn add underscore` and also added the google maps script `gmaps_google.js` currently under vendor/javascripts folder which has been added to my resolved paths in webpacker.yml  `app/javascript/packs/application.js file looks like:

```js
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("gmaps_google")

import "bootstrap";
import 'underscore'
import "../stylesheets/application";

window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
```

Here is my actual show.html.erb view and attempted load of the map

```html
<div style='width: 800px;'>
  <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
</div>

<script>
  const handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
    markers = handler.addMarkers([
      {
        "lat": <%= @user.latitude %>,
        "lng": <%= @user.longitude %>,
        "infowindow": "<%= @user.full_name %>'s location"
      }
    ]);
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
    handler.getMap().setZoom(17);
  });
</script>
```

Yet I still get no map loading on the page an error that says 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: Gmaps is not defined`

It does load, and the error goes away when I load the gmaps script from an external CDN source in my HTML head, as this question suggests: [Gmaps is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44704324/gmaps-is-not-defined)

So it is clearly just the loading/availability of that google_maps.js script. It's too massive of a file to show here, but here is the link to the working CDN version: cdn.jsdelivr.net/gmaps4rails/2.1.2/gmaps4rails.js

Copy-pasting that into my google_maps.js file doesn't help though. And I'm trying to figure out how I can get it to work with the Google Maps script residing within my Rails application and the webpack Rails 6 world is still very new to me. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The quick-and-dirty way is just load the gmaps4rails code (and underscore) from CDN instead of Webpack. Since you're just using a `<script>` tag to build the map, Webpack is not helping you there.

If you'd like to try using Webpack anyways, read on.

Understand that Webpack isolates itself from the global scope; unlike Sprockets, objects or values you import in Webpack will not be available in `<script>` tags or the browser console. If you want this behavior, you have to configure it by hand.

Looking at the gmaps4rails script, it appears not to be module-aware and assumes it's evaluated in the global scope (where underscore is available). In other words, it's not module-friendly. But we can make it play nice.

We need to tell Webpack to treat `this` in the gmaps4rails script as `window`, i.e., the global scope, and to "provide" underscore (or nearly interchangeable lodash, as below) since it assumes the `_` lib is available in its scope.

In your shell:

```sh
$ yarn add imports-loader lodash
```

In `config/webpack/environment.js`:

```js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.loaders.append('gmap4rails', {
  test: /gmaps_google/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'imports-loader',
      options: 'this=>window',
    },
  ],
})

environment.plugins.append(
  'lodash',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    _: 'lodash',
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

Assuming you have set up your google scripts correctly per the [gmaps4rails README](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails#requirements), this should do the trick.

---

I've created a demo app with a working example in the `example/gmap4rails` branch (bring your own Google Maps API key): https://github.com/rossta/rails6-webpacker-demo/tree/example/gmaps4rails

Comment: Thanks, can I ask where the 'gmap4rails' and `/gmaps_google/` arguments/values are coming from? I still receive the same error with lodash or underscore, and otherwise, have set things up according to the readme. I assume that `environment.loaders.append` method in general is where I'm missing some understanding.

Comment: The 'gmap4rails' arg is arbitrary; it's necessary to name the "loader" in the @rails/webpacker `environment.loaders` interface. The `test` argument is a path-matcher; when a module that matches that name is loaded, then the specified rules apply. 

I updated my answer with a demo app. Hope that helps you debug.