# Leaflet with Webpack in Rails 6. L.timeline is not a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, leaflet, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

This looks just like the question @rossta answered for [Gmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59042437/gmaps-with-rails-6-webpack), but I don't understand the problem and answer well enough to make his suggestion work.

The error is: `Uncaught TypeError: L.timeline is not a function
    at Object.success (mapTwo.js:14)` Line 14 is `var timelineData = L.timeline(data_data, {`. Complete code below.

I removed the leaflet gems that work in Rails 5.2 and in console

```
yarn add leaflet
yarn add leaflet.timeline
```

and code:

```
// app/javascript/packs/application.js
import "core-js/stable"
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime"
import '../stylesheets/application'
window.jQuery = $
window.$      = $
import 'leaflet'
import "leaflet.timeline"
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("trix")
require("@rails/actiontext")
require("jquery") 
import "bootstrap"
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap'

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})

<!-- map/index.html.erb -->
<div id="map_two"></div>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'mapTwo' %> 


// javascript/packs/mapTwo.js  called from map/index.html.erb
console.log('Hello from /javascript/packs/mapTwo.js')
var mapVar = L.map("map_two", {
  center: [34.040951, -118.258579],
  zoom: 13
});
L.tileLayer('https://crores.s3.amazonaws.com/tiles/bkm/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(mapVar);
$.getJSON("map/line_data.geojson", function(data_data) {
  var timelineData = L.timeline(data_data, {
    style: function(data_data) {
      return {
        stroke: true,
        fillOpacity: 0.5
      }
    }, // end style: function(data_data)
    waitToUpdateMap: true,
    onEachFeature: function(data_data, layer) {
        layer.bindTooltip(data_data.properties.popup, {
          direction: 'top'
        });
      } // onEachFeature: 
  }); // end let timelineData = L.timeline
  var timelineControl = L.timelineSliderControl({
    enableKeyboardControls: true,
    steps: 100,
    start: 1885,
    end: 1928,
  });
  timelineControl.addTo(mapVar);
  timelineData.addTo(mapVar);
  timelineControl.addTimelines(timelineData);
}); //  end $.getJSON
```

My attempt at applying the solution offered:

```
// config/webpack/environment.js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.append('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery',
    // 'window.Jquery': 'jquery', 
    Popper: ['popper.js' ,'default'],
    L: 'leaflet' // didn't help
  }))

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59042437/gmaps-with-rails-6-webpack
environment.loaders.append('leaflet', {
  test: /map/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'imports-loader',
      options: 'this=>window',
    },
  ],
})

environment.plugins.append(
  'lodash',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    _: 'lodash',
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "license": "ISC",
  "main": "application.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actiontext": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.1",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "core-js": "^3.5.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jqueryui": "^1.11.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.6.0",
    "leaflet.timeline": "^1.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mapbox": "^1.0.0-beta10",
    "ol": "^6.1.1",
    "ol-ext": "^3.1.7",
    "ol-layerswitcher": "^3.4.0",
    "ol-loupe": "^1.0.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.3",
    "trix": "^1.0.0",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you have used `import 'leaflet.timeline'` anywhere.

Comment: Also, please post your `package.json` file.

Comment: `import 'leaflet' 
import "leaflet.timeline" ` Same error `L.timeline is not a function` Will add `package.json to OP. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your setup:

1. The `'leaflet.timeline'` plugin assumes the leaflet module is available as the global variable `'L'`. The source code of the plugin shows this to be true (on master at the time of this post): https://github.com/skeate/Leaflet.timeline/blob/b7a8406f5a9a66ccdbcaf73465baaedadec76d1f/src/Timeline.js#L1
2. (I believe) You are using more than one entry point on the page at one time: `'application.js'` and `'mapTwo.js'`. Rails calls entry points "packs", so everything in `app/javascript/packs` is a separate entry point to Webpack. Webpack recommends 1 entry point *per page*; without extra configuration, multiple entry points on one page can lead to surprising behavior, especially with regards to global variables (see #1).

To elaborate further on issue 2, with your current configuration, Webpack doesn't know you want to use two entry points on the page; it bundles one instance of the Leaflet module in the application pack and another instance of the Leaflet module in the mapTwo pack. It bundles the Leaflet module in mapTwo because you added the ProvidePlugin configuration `L: 'leaflet'`, which says, basically, add `var L = require('leaflet')` to every module that references `L`.

So there are a few possible fixes:

1. Move your `import 'leaflet.timeline'` into mapTwo.js and remove `import 'leaflet'` from application.js. You don't need `import 'leaflet'` given your ProvidePlugin config. This is the easiest fix to address the short-term issue of `L.timeline is not a function`. It does not prevent you from bundling modules like Leaflet twice when using multiple entry points on the page, say if you were to need to add `import 'leaflet'` somewhere in the application.js dependency graph. **OR**
2. Don't split up your packs; consolidate all your existing code in the dependency graph of `'application.js'`. You may need to wrap your existing mapTwo code in callback, i.e., `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', callback)`. **OR**
3. Use the [SplitChunksPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin), which is a way of sharing modules across Webpack "chunks" which, in your case, means the entry points, application.js and mapTwo.js. This means, keep your existing code in separate packs along with additional changes described in more detail in the Rails Webpack docs: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/webpack.md#add-splitchunks-webpack-v4. You may need to also wrap mapTwo.js code in the DOMContentLoaded listener, as in 2.

Finally, remove this code from your configuration; as this was copied from another solution, it's not adding any value to your setup:

```
environment.loaders.append('leaflet', {
  test: /map/, 
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'imports-loader',
      options: 'this=>window',
    },
  ],
})
```

You can also likely combine the separate ProvidePlugin groups, i.e., you don't need a separate one for lodash.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer which helps because I'm using this example (which worked before I tried webpack) to see if I could make webpacker work for me before moving to OpenLayers which doesn't seem to have gem support. I no longer have the error (nor any errors) but the page isn't working yet so may be back with more questions.  


I seem to get the same result with `leaflet` and `leaflet.timeline` in application.js and removing `L: 'leaflet'` from environment.js as I do with your fix #1. The former seems like a more straightforward approach. Is there a downside to this?

Comment: Not sure I follow your question without the whole context. Maybe it will help if I reiterate: if your app is small, I recommend option 2. If your app is large and you insist on multiple packs, try for option 3.

Comment: Thanks. Small app. I removed `L: 'leaflet'` from environment.js and left `leaflet` and `leaflet.timeline` in application.js. Seemed simpler. But I assume I now have a Javascript problem. I'll look harder at the callback.

Comment: I'm marking this solved but since the problem has changed and I want the solutions to make since, I've started over at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59744187/rails-leaflet-webpack-blank-page. Thank you @rossta