# Rails Leaflet Webpack blank page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, openlayers, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

This a continuation of a [related problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59670743/leaflet-with-webpack-in-rails-6-l-timeline-is-not-a-function) that @rossta fixed part of, but now the problem is moved so thought I'd start over.

No errors and the script is completing (verified by console.log outputs in the script). The body element shows up. This worked with gem leaflet and now webpack in Rails 5.2, but not now in Rails 6 with webpack

I moved the script into the page to isolate the problem `map/index.html.erb`

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% provide(:title, 'Map') %>
<h4>This is map/index.html.erb and is put in layouts/map.html.erb.</h4>
  <div id="map_two" class="map clearfix"></div>   -->
  <script>
    function makeMapTwo() {

    console.log('Hello from makeMapTwo in map/index.html.erb')
        var mapVar = L.map("map_two", { center: [34.040951, -118.258579], zoom: 13 });
        L.tileLayer('https://crores.s3.amazonaws.com/tiles/bkm/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(mapVar);

        $.getJSON("line_data.geojson", function (data_data) {
          var timelineData = L.timeline(data_data, {
            style: function(data_data){
              return {
                stroke: true,
                fillOpacity: 0.5
              }
              }, // end style: function(data_data)
            waitToUpdateMap: true,
            onEachFeature: function(data_data, layer) {
              layer.bindTooltip(data_data.properties.popup, { direction: 'top' } );
            } // onEachFeature:
          }); // end let timelineData = L.timeline
          var timelineControl = L.timelineSliderControl({
            enableKeyboardControls: true,
            steps: 100,
            start: 1885,
            end: 1928,
          });
          timelineData.addTo(mapVar); 
          timelineControl.addTo(mapVar);
          timelineControl.addTimelines(timelineData);
          }); //  end $.getJSON
        }; // end function makeMapTwo()

    $(document).ready(function() {
      makeMapTwo();
    });
  </script>
```

`views/layouts/map.html.erb`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <h6>This is layouts/map.html.erb. A note to remind me that header is happening twice in maps TODO</h6>
    <%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
     <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload', 'data-turbolinks-suppress-warning': true %>
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
     <style> 
       .map {
         height: 400px;
         width: 100%
       }
     </style>
     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %> <!-- the navbar -->
  <body class="container" data-mapbox-token="<%= ENV['MAPBOX_TOKEN'] %>">
    <%= yield %>
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
  </body>
</html>
```

and `app/javascript/packs/application.js`:

```
import "core-js/stable"
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime"
import '../stylesheets/application'
window.jQuery = $
window.$      = $
import 'leaflet'
import "leaflet.timeline"
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("trix")
require("@rails/actiontext")
require("jquery") 
import "bootstrap"
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap'

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

`config/webpack/environment.js`:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.append('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js' ,'default'],
  }))

module.exports = environment
```

`package.json`

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.append('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js' ,'default'],
  }))

module.exports = environment
```

Debugging needed, but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: I gave up on this and am getting OpenLayers, OpenLayers ol-ext, and jQuery via CDN and the page loads fine. As many have stated Webpacker is not easy. But I did learn some of it, but not enough to solve this. What helped me was finding that ol-ext was available via CDN

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe that this change had any effect but it did.

Changed the map_two in `<div id="map_two"...`  `var mapVar = L.map("map_two"...` to just `map` and it loads. I was using map_two because when I was experimenting earlier I thought the two pages I was using with just `map` were getting confused. I also tried `map-two` and it didn't work either (not that I would have expected it, but I still do't understand what is happening. I restarted the server between the changes to be more sure of what is going on.