# Rails 6, webpack, and tippy.js giving "tippy is not defined" - Where do I call the tippy() function?

Tags: webpack, hadoop-yarn, ruby-on-rails-6, tippyjs

I'm relatively new to using Webpack with Rails.  I'm attempting to install [tippy.js](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v6/getting-started/) on a Rails 6 app, but I'm having trouble getting it accessible to the view. (I can get it to work if I just include the tippy.js CDN in a script tag in the view, but I can't get it to work by using webpack/yarn.)

Per the tippy.js [instructions](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v6/getting-started/), I've installed tippy.js with yarn. My **`package.json`** file:

```
{
  "//": [
    "moment - used in time_zones",
    "popper.js - needed for bootstrap"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.3-1",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "jquery-ujs": "^1.2.2",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "tippy.js": "^6.2.3",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {}
}
```

The instructions then say to import tippy and its CSS, so I did that in **`app/javascript/packs/application.js`**:

```
import "core-js/stable";

require("@rails/ujs").start();
require("jquery");

import tippy from "tippy.js";
import 'tippy.js/dist/tippy.css';
console.log("loaded tippy");
```

Then, in my **`index.html.erb`** view, I follow their [creation](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v6/creation/) examples to create a sample button, and, per their [nothing is working FAQ](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v6/faq/), call tippy at the end of the body:

```
<button data-tippy-content="Tooltip">Text</button>

...

<script>
  tippy('[data-tippy-content]');
</script>
```

However, I don't get a tooltip, and in the console, I get an "Uncaught ReferenceError: tippy is not defined" for the line containing `tippy('[data-tippy-content]');`.

## Things I've tried:

### Putting Tippy in ProvidePlugin within config/webpack/environment.js

I had to do this to get jQuery to work, so I figured I might have to do something similar for tippy.js:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    tippy: 'tippy.js'
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

Didn't change anything; still got the ReferenceError in my view. I suspect I might be doing something wrong here; I could find a bunch of examples of how to ProvidePlugin for jQuery, but not much online for anything else.

### Removing `tippy('[data-tippy-content]');` from the view and putting it in app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
import "core-js/stable";

require("@rails/ujs").start();
require("jquery");

import tippy from "tippy.js";
import 'tippy.js/dist/tippy.css';
tippy('[data-tippy-content]');
console.log("loaded tippy");
```

I no longer got the ReferenceError, but the tooltips didn't work either. So somehow tippy didn't get initialized in any way that the view recognized.

### Using the exact CDN example from their [nothing is working FAQ](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v6/faq/) in the view:

```
<body>
    <button>Text</button>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@6"></script>
    <script>
      tippy('button', {content: 'tooltip'});
    </script>
</body>
```

Works -- I get the tooltip and no console errors -- but it defeats the whole point of using webpack to have to include CDN script tags in my views.

---

How and where should I call the `tippy('[data-tippy-content]');` so that my view will properly include a tippy.js tooltip for all tags with the data-tippy-content attribute?

Comment: Searching around some more, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59043633/1151015) seems to indicate that things included in webpack aren't available to <script> tags. I'm still not quite sure how to extrapolate this to tippy.js, though; it sure seems like I need to use environment.js to make tippy available, but I haven't figured out exactly how to make it work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add tippy.js easily in rails 6 :-

- `yarn add tippy.js`
- Go to `app/javascripts/packs/application.js` & add the following lines

```
import tippy from 'tippy.js';
import 'tippy.js/dist/tippy.css';
window.tippy = tippy;
```

- Now use tippy in your rails views like the following

```
      tippy('#myButton', {
        animation: 'scale',
        content: 'Hi I am working',
      });
```

Comment: Adding the line window.tippy = tippy; fixed it.. but why?

Comment: @cratag I would recommend reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61777360/rails-6-webpacker-calling-javascript-function-from-rails-view for answers to your last question